# Выбрать элемент с выпадающего списка

Tags: c#

Доброе утро.
Не могу выбрать элемент из выпадающего списка.
[image: Вот так должно выглядеть]

Делал следующее:

1. Вписывал текст

   ```
   webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Advert_category_id").InnerText = "Wedding/Event Services";
   ```
2. Задавал value используя следующие команды, в разных последовательностях, как только не крутил.

   ```
   webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Advert_category_id").SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
   webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Advert_category_id").InvokeMember("onchange");
   webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Advert_category_id").InvokeMember("submit");
   webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Advert_category_id").InvokeMember("value", "84");
   ```

   Проблема еще в том, что этот код выбирает нужный мне вариант, но он не выводится в поле. Т.е. только при нажатии на поле, после выполнения кода, можно увидеть, что нужный вариант выбран. Но такой подход тоже не верен, т.к. в следующем выпадающем списке под названием SUB CATEGORY не подгружаются нужные данные (данные остаются с категории выбранной по умолчанию - Professional)
3. Пытался экспериментировать с разными id-шниками. Ничего не помогает :(

Сам сайт https://list.asiandirectoryapp.com/advert/create
(для просмотра необходима регистрация)
Сделал второй акк, что бы лишнее время не теряли на регистрацию
fovogaze@p33.org
qwerty123
Интересующий код

```html
   <div style="display:none"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="Advert_city_id">City</label><select class="form-control" name="Advert[city_id]" id="Advert_city_id">
</select><div class="help-block error" id="Advert_city_id_em_" style="display:none"></div></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label required" for="Advert_category_id">Category <span class="required">*</span></label><select class="form-control" name="Advert[category_id]" id="Advert_category_id">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="35">Beauty, Health &amp; Fitness</option>
<option value="19">Education</option>
<option value="21">Entertainment</option>
<option value="27">Food, Drink &amp; Sweet Centres</option>
<option value="39">Home Services</option>
<option value="116">Jobs/Careers</option>
<option value="43">Motoring</option>
<option value="50">Other Services</option>
<option value="1">Professional</option>
<option value="51">Property Improvements</option>
<option value="84">Wedding/Event Services</option>
<option value="117">Whats On Guide</option>
</select><div class="help-block error" id="Advert_category_id_em_" style="display:none"></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label required" for="Advert_categoryList">Sub category <span class="required">*</span></label><select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="Advert[categoryList][]" id="Advert_categoryList">
<option value="2">Accountants</option>
<option value="4">Claims</option>
<option value="123">Clothing Manufacturers</option>
<option value="6">Estate &amp; Letting Agents</option>
<option value="7">Finance/Mortgages</option>
<option value="8">Graphic &amp; Web Design</option>
<option value="9">Immigration</option>
<option value="10">Information Technology</option>
<option value="11">Insurance</option>
<option value="13">Mobile Apps - Mobile Phones</option>
<option value="14">Online Marketing/ SEO</option>
<option value="18">Print</option>
<option value="15">Retail and Wholesale</option>
<option value="16">Solicitors - Lawyers</option>
<option value="17">Travel Agents</option>
</select><div class="help-block error" id="Advert_categoryList_em_" style="display:none"></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label required" for="Advert_name">Company Name <span class="required">*</span></label><input class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name" name="Advert[name]" id="Advert_name" type="text" maxlength="100" /><div class="help-block error" id="Advert_name_em_" style="display:none"></div></div>
```

P.S. Все поля заполнить могу, кнопки нажимать так же, а вот с выпадающим списком беда.

Благодарю за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1):

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("имя тега").SetAttribute("value", "значение которое нужно, обычно числовое");
```

http://forum.vingrad.ru/topic-295349.html